# Two mechanisms of authentication: Kerberos and HTTP basic

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I have a springboot application which uses usual HTTP basic authentication using `spring-security-ldap`.

Later I modified it to use Single Sign On (Kerberos) authentication using `spring-security-kerberos-core` and `spring-security-kerberos-web`.

Everything is working fine so far.

Now I need to use both mechanisms. The idea is to use SSO for the front-end application, so that users are logged in automatically. And to use HTTP basic (username/password) for REST interface or for testing.

Probably I need to have two entry points (e.g. '/login' for SSO and '/login-userpass' for HTTP basic). Is it a correct approach? Or are there other ways to implement it?

It seems to me a common requirement but I'm not able to find examples of how to implement this.

EDIT:
Actually, it's a [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654124/spring-security-kerberos-chained-with-basic). And the accepted answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Kerberos with Spring, but I have previously implemented an application with both basic, form and CA SSO. However without looking at some code, particularly WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I can only give general guidlines.

With Spring you need a number of authentication filteres mapped to different URLs, these will intercept the login, do 401 challenge if needed, and then create an unauthenticated Authentication instance. The typical filters are BasicAuthenticationFilter and UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, and you need to find the one for KerBeros.

Later the unauthenticated authentications are give to the AuthenticationProviderManager which find the appropriate AuthenticationProvider to perform the authentication. This is where you do you database query with password hash (potentially SSO callback) and if the user is authenticated you create a new Authentication, typically you would want to extend AbstractAuthenticationToken or select one of the existing authentication. Remember to copy the details for the unauthenticated Authentication.

In Spring 4 AuthenticationProvider are configured using AuthenticationManagerBuilder, this is done in the configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which you need to override.

Remember that you can have a single filter and many AuthenticationProviders or many filters and a single AuthenticationProvider, depending on your needs.

The application I have access to at the moment has a single form login, but some additional hidden fields (and stuff in the session), controls which of the 4 available AuthenticationProviders will be responsible for authentication, and different Authentication classes are created based on which provider authenticated the user, so we can restrict some areas of the application to specific Authentication types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I understand the mechanics in general but I would really need a piece of code where I can see all the details.